# Push to Nexus 3 NuGet-repository from Jenkins CI without being asked for credentials

Tags: jenkins, nuget, nexus3

This is driving me nuts. I have installed Nexus 3 OSS to use as a private NuGet-repository and created a user foe jenkins. I got an ApiKey for the jenkins user the way the documentation shows and now I try to push my packages to the repo with

```
nuget push .\AMAP.*.symbols.nupkg -Source http://nexus.local:8081/repository/nuget-hosted/ -ApiKey <JenkinsApiKeyHere>
```

But if I do this I am asked for username and password. I tried to set username and password to my configuration as suggested by some sources found on the net like this:

```
nuget sources update -Name my-nuget -username jenkins -password <supersecretjenkinspwd>
```

But still I am asked for username and password!? By the way, the anonymous access to nexus is granted as shown in the [sonatype docs](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/security/anonymous-access).

As you can see from above I am trying to do this from a jenkins build server and I already tried the nexus artifact uploader plugin without success. It fails with a NullPointer:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sp.sd.nexusartifactuploader.steps.NexusArtifactUploaderStep.getUsername(NexusArtifactUploaderStep.java:132)
```

So I think it has the same problem. How can I achieve to push my NuGet-packages to Nexus without user interaction?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution myself. I needed to add the ***NuGet API-Key Realm*** to the active realms. By default it is not active thus preventing the ApiKey from being considered as valid credential.
This is done under **Settings -> Security -> Realms**.

Comment: hi Frank. Am new to Jenkins. Am doing nuget push <artifact> -Source <repo_url>. When this is run in pipeline script, am getting an un-authorization error. Can u please help me out where exactly I will have to update api key, user name and password in jenkins? And where can I find this setting that u r talking about?

Comment: Hey I found it! Thanks. It was the settings in nexus oss

Comment: Do you need both username:password and API key to upload with nuget push? Or either is good enough?